# Remap SQL Using Case

Tags: sql, metabase, bigquery-udf

I currently have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT `source`.`video_id` AS `video_id`, count(*) AS `count`
FROM (SELECT 
 *,
 (SELECT param.value.string_value 
 FROM UNNEST(event_params) AS param
WHERE param.key="content_type") as content_type,
 (SELECT param.value.string_value
 FROM UNNEST(event_params) AS param WHERE param.key="item_id") as video_id
FROM `analytics_275841270.events_*`, UNNEST(event_params) as event  
where event.value.string_value = 'v-academy') `source`
GROUP BY `video_id`
ORDER BY `count` DESC, `video_id` ASC
limit 5
```

which produces the following result:

sql n result

[image]

I want to remap my video_id into a string like "video26".

How do I concatenate the `video_id` with a static string?

Answer (score 0):

If this is SQL Server, then you can use the `CONCAT()` function.

More can be found on this [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2985/concatenate-sql-server-columns-into-a-string-with-concat/).

You can simply write `CONCAT('video', video_id)` in the `SELECT` statement.